# How to run SOLR service on a single Port in the Azure app service?

Tags: solr, azure, paas

We host the SOLR as an app service in the Azure PaaS. It seems that SOLR runs on the different port every time.

Is there any way to restrict the SOLR to run on a single port only?

Comment: I think HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT should be used to run Solr on a single port. Check this one https://www.getfishtank.com/blog/installing-solr-app-service-in-sitecore-azure-paas

Comment: Is it Azure IaaS or PaaS?

Comment: @HimmatSinghDulawat It is PaaS

Comment: @SumitHelaiya I don't see any option to run it on single port in that link

Comment: web.config screenshot <httpPlatform processPath="%HOME%\site\wwwroot\bin\solr.cmd"
       arguments="start -p %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%"
       startupTimeLimit="20"
       startupRetryCount="10"
       stdoutLogEnabled="true"> try by replacing %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% with port number like 8983.

Comment: @Astle - Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Astle actually you created an app service for Solr. So It contains a URL so there is no need for Port 80 or 443.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,Azure app service will `dynamically assign ports` within the platform.By default, it's `not allowed` to restrict one specific port only.
While you can try some alternative workaround:

1. Try setting up a `rverse proxy` using `nginx` or `IIS` to make it listen the port and forward the reuqest from solr app.
2. Try to use a `VM` instead of Paas Service.You can try to install a stand-alone instance on VM server with more control over network and without restriction on ports.
   Hope it helps!